# PDO do not work when i check ip

Tags: php, pdo

Today i tired pass from the mysql connection to PDO. And i met a problem.

```
require('config.php');

function GetAll($query, $params) {
    global $db;
    try {
        $sth = $db->prepare($query);
    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {

        return null;
    }
    try {
        $sth->execute($params);
    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {

        return null;
    }
    $result = $sth->fetchAll();
    return $result;
}

if ($fetch = GetAll("SELECT `loggedip` FROM `ipcheck` WHERE `loggedip`=':ipcheck'", array(":ipcheck" => $iptocheck))) {

    $resultx = $db->prepare("SELECT `failedattempts` FROM `ipcheck` WHERE `loggedip`='$iptocheck'");
    $resultx->execute();
    while ($rowx = $resultx->fetch()) {
        ;
    }
    $loginattempts_total = $rowx['failedattempts'];
    echo "$loginattempts_total";
    if ($loginattempts_total > $maxfailedattempt) {
        header(sprintf("Location: %s", $forbidden_url));
        exit;
    }
}
```

this is my script. in PDO and his don't work. when my ip is banned should not see, but i see the page. PLEASE HELP ((

Comment: A few suggestions: don't put quotes around your parameter in the prepared statement. Also, executing a query in an 'if' condition isn't a clean style. And then, you're using stringninterpolation instead of a prepared statement in the mext query.

Comment: It's one fragment, when ip is bloked you see 403 page, but his do not show me 403 page. Sorry for my bad english (